# Combine two armatures and keep weight painting?

Tags: armature, export, weight-painting, actions

So I have an animation of a gun firing, and an animation of a flying pear enemy, and I want to combine their two armatures so I can export them together as one action into a game engine. I've tried to ctrl+j the armatures, but the weight painting gets messed up. I've tried making a new armature that has one massive bone for the gun, and one massive bone for the Pear, but the weight painting still won't work, since there are already other bones. Any help is appreciated.

[Pear Animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJDTd.gif)

[Gun Animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSjaF.gif)

[Before I ctrl+j the armatures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMAi0.jpg)

[After I ctrl+j the armatures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEmEG.jpg)

Comment: did you make sure that the bones of the 2 armatures had different names? Also, are you sure you want to join these 2 armatures? Seems weird, but I don't know a lot about game engines...

Comment: @moonboots I tried renaming all the bones, but I don't think I matched the vertex groups. Will try that now. Also yeah I'm sure I need to join the armatures.

Comment: Yeah it didn't work